# Manual force-authentication of a user without issuing an authentication request

Tags: servicestack

I have a ServiceStack application that coexists with mvc5 in a single web project.  The only purpose of the mvc5 part is to host a single controller action that receives a callback from janrain for javascript initiated social login.  I could receive this callback in a SS service request, too, but then I don't know how I would do a redirect to the returnUrl that is passed through all the way from the javascript context.  Even if I was able to figure this out, my question would still be the same.

Inside of the controller action, once I verify the janrain provided token resolves to a user in my system, I need to manually tell ServiceStack "hey trust me - this person is authorized".

All my searches lead to some code along the lines of the following snippet:

```
 var authService = AppHostBase.Resolve<AuthService>();
                authService.RequestContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ToRequestContext();
                var AuthResponse = authService.Authenticate(new Auth
                {
                    provider = "credentials",
                    UserName = user.user_id,
                    Password = user.password,
                    RememberMe = true
                });
```

My first problem here is that I store hashed passwords (I support social login as well as manual login), so I don't know the user's password (and I shouldn't).

My second problem is that this code seems to only work for SS 3.X and not 4.X.  I requires a ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.dll that is mysteriously missing from 4.X.

Is there a short and precise way to manually authenticate a user with SS on the server side?

Thanks

EDIT:
So far this is what I am doing: (This is not final code - I have commented out some things I don't know what to do with):

```
public class UsernameOnlyAuthorizationService : Service
    {
        public object Post(UsernameOnlyLoginRequest request)
        {
            var authProvider = new UsernameOnlyAuthProvider();
            authProvider.Authenticate(this, GetSession(), new Authenticate()
            {
                UserName = request.username,
                Password = "NotRelevant",
                RememberMe = true
            });

            return HttpResult.Redirect(request.returnUrl);
        }
    }


public class UsernameOnlyAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
    {
        public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
        {
            var authRepo = authService.TryResolve<IAuthRepository>().AsUserAuthRepository(authService.GetResolver());
            ReferScienceDataContext db = authService.TryResolve<ReferScienceDataContext>();
            var session = authService.GetSession();
            IUserAuth userAuth;
            var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == userName);

            if (user != null)
            {
                //AssertNotLocked(userAuth);

                //session.PopulateWith(userAuth);
                session.Id = user.Id.ToString();
                session.UserName = user.Username;
                session.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                session.LastName = user.LastName;
                session.IsAuthenticated = true;
                session.UserAuthId = user.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                session.ProviderOAuthAccess = authRepo.GetUserAuthDetails(session.UserAuthId)
                    .ConvertAll(x => (IAuthTokens)x);

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

And from within my Janrain success callback code I call it so:

```
HostContext.ResolveService<UsernameOnlyAuthorizationService>().Post(new UsernameOnlyLoginRequest() {username = user.Username, returnUrl= returnUrl});
```

This seems to work nicely, however, I can't get it to remember my session across browser closes.  I am hardcoding RememberMe = true - why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this by creating an internal service, which you can call from your MVC5 controller action, where you only require to pass the username of the user you have authenticated.

```cs
public class JanrainSuccessService : Service
{
    public void CreateSessionFor(string username)
    {
        var repository = TryResolve<IAuthRepository>().AsUserAuthRepository(GetResolver());
        var user = repository.GetUserAuthByUserName(username);
        var session = GetSession();
        session.PopulateWith(user);
        session.IsAuthenticated = true;
        session.UserAuthId = user.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        session.ProviderOAuthAccess = repository.GetUserAuthDetails(session.UserAuthId).ConvertAll(x => (IAuthTokens)x);
    }
}
```

The code in this method, is effectively the same could that is used by the `CredentialsAuthProvider`, but has the advantage of not requiring the password of the user. *(See the `TryAuthenticate` [method here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/CredentialsAuthProvider.cs) for original code)*

In your MVC5 controller action method you would need to call:

```cs
HostContext.ResolveService<JanrainSuccessService>().CreateSessionFor(user.user_id);
```

*This assumes that you have a valid repository of users configured to match username's against.*

---

You should update your code to be:

```cs
public class UsernameOnlyAuthorizationService : Service
{
    public object Post(UsernameOnlyLoginRequest request)
    {
        var authProvider = new UsernameOnlyAuthProvider();
        authProvider.Authenticate(this, GetSession(), new Authenticate()
        {
            UserName = request.username,
            Password = "NotRelevant",
            RememberMe = true
        });

        // Remember the session
        base.Request.AddSessionOptions(SessionOptions.Permanent);

        return HttpResult.Redirect(request.returnUrl);
    }
}

public class UsernameOnlyAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
    {
        var authRepo = authService.TryResolve<IAuthRepository>().AsUserAuthRepository(authService.GetResolver());
        ReferScienceDataContext db = authService.TryResolve<ReferScienceDataContext>();
        var session = authService.GetSession();
        var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == userName);

        if (user == null)
            return false;

        session.Id = user.Id.ToString();
        session.UserName = user.Username;
        session.FirstName = user.FirstName;
        session.LastName = user.LastName;
        session.IsAuthenticated = true;
        session.UserAuthId = user.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        session.ProviderOAuthAccess = authRepo.GetUserAuthDetails(session.UserAuthId).ConvertAll(x => (IAuthTokens)x);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution.  I am going to give it a try and hopefully I can accept your post as the answer imminently. Thank you.

Comment: I noticed that you wrote this little authenticator class as an SS service.  Technically, this could have been any plain old class that can be dependency injected, correct?  At first I thought this was a security problem because I have been thinking of SS as remotely callable services.  However, it seems these Service inherited classes can be invoked as a local service or remote service.  Am I correct in thinking that JanrainSuccessService cannot be called remotely because there is no route defined?  Obviously I don't want any remote javascript application to be able to impersonate anyone...

Comment: @t316 I added it as a service because it automatically wires up the session resolve, and there is less code to resolve the other dependancies. But you are right you don't *have* to do it there, as long as you resolve the dependancies from the `HostContext` yourself. As for security, there is no access to that method, because there is no route to it. And the method name isn't an `HTTP` method name such as `Get` or `Post`. You can confirm this by viewing the metadata, where the method will not be shown.

Comment: @t316 If you were still worried about this method, you could add this attribute `[Restrict(LocalhostOnly = true)]` to be explicit about the security. Though as I say it is unnecessary.

Comment: I finally tried this method.  It doesn't allow Authorized services to be called.  I suspect it is missing the cookie part but I put in something like this at the end of your code and it still doesn't work:
var httpRes = this.Request.Response as IHttpResponse;
            if (httpRes != null)
            {
                httpRes.Cookies.AddPermanentCookie(HttpHeaders.XUserAuthId, session.UserAuthId);
            }
Is there any way to subclass An CredentialAuthProvider, override onauthenticate (to ignore password) and look the username up?  How would I call it?

Comment: Is there anyway I can create a specific AuthProvider and call it from within my janrain success callback?

Comment: @t316 I'll need to get back to you on this later. I'll try get a fully working example to help.

Comment: Scott - with your help and some other examples I have a somewhat working example.  I have edited the question with that code. Would you be kind enough to see whether this is an ok approach and if so why I can't get servicestack to remember my session across browser closes?  Thanks

Comment: @t316 You can safely remove the commented lines in your code, you have effectively written that functionality yourself. :) You can also remove the line `IUserAuth userAuth;`. To remember your session, you just need to add this line in your `POST` method: `base.Request.AddSessionOptions(SessionOptions.Permanent);`.

Comment: @t316 I have updated my answer with the relevant changes to your code.

Comment: Thanks Scott - that works well.  It doesn't survive a server restart, but I think that's a different issue (which I have not noticed before).  Any idea why, when I restart my service stack service project in Visual Studio, it re-requires authentication again?  This is not really a problem, but I am curious.

Comment: @t316 This will happen if your session provider is the default In-Memory cache provider. If you need persistence then consider using a cache provider such as Redis.